# Quitting Tkinter drop down menu

Tags: python, python-3.x, drop-down-menu, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have a drop down menu and want it to have to option to log off. I need the menu to close when log off is selected, but I don't want the whole program to close.

I have tried methods like root.quit() but it says root is not defined, even though it is. What is the best way to close the menu.  The code for the menu is:

```
from tkinter import *

def edit_or_retrieve():

    root = Tk()
    root.title("Main Menu")

    menu = Frame(root)
    menu.pack(pady = 5, padx = 50)
    var = StringVar(root)

    options = [
        'Enter',
        'Edit', 
        'Retrieve',
        'Report 1 - Dates of birth',
        'Report 2 - Home phone numbers',
        'Report 3 - Home addresses',
        'Log off',

]
    option = OptionMenu(menu, var, options[0], *options, command=function)

    var.set('Select')

    option.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

    root.mainloop()



def function(value):
    if value == 'Edit':
        edit()
    if value == 'Enter':
        enter()
    if value == 'Retrieve':
        display()
    if value == 'Report 1 - Dates of birth':
         reportone()
    if value == 'Report 2 - Home phone numbers':
         reporttwo()
    if value == 'Report 3 - Home addresses':
         reportthree()
    if value == 'Log off':
         #this is where the command or function name needs to go,  
         #however I am not sure what it should be.
```

Comment: root variable has function [scope](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html) only

Answer (score 2):

The problem with calling `root.quit()` in `function()` was caused by the fact that it's a variable local to the `edit_or_retrieve()` function. This can be fixed by passing it as an argument to `function()`, but unfortunately, the `OptionMenu` widget is the thing that does this, and you can't modify it.

However you can workaround this and pass extra arguments to the function by creating a short `lambda` function that acts as a software ["shim"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shim_(computing)) and passes the extra argument to `function()` when *it's* called.

Below is your code with the modifications to do this:

```
from tkinter import *

def edit_or_retrieve():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Main Menu")

    menu = Frame(root)
    menu.pack(pady=5, padx=50)
    var = StringVar(root)

    options = ['Enter',
               'Edit',
               'Retrieve',
               'Report 1 - Dates of birth',
               'Report 2 - Home phone numbers',
               'Report 3 - Home addresses',
               'Log off',]

    option = OptionMenu(menu, var, *options,
                        # use lambda to pass local var as extra argument
                        command=lambda x: function(x, root))

    var.set('Select')
    option.grid(row=1, column=1)

    root.mainloop()

def function(value, root):  # note added "root" argument
    if value == 'Edit':
        edit()
    if value == 'Enter':
        enter()
    if value == 'Retrieve':
        display()
    if value == 'Report 1 - Dates of birth':
         reportone()
    if value == 'Report 2 - Home phone numbers':
         reporttwo()
    if value == 'Report 3 - Home addresses':
         reportthree()
    if value == 'Log off':
        root.quit()

edit_or_retrieve()
```